# importar columna de excel a comboboxcolumn de datagrid C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

Estoy intentando importar un excel a datagrid, algunos datos si pasan a las columnas pero una cplumna es DataGridViewComboBoxColumn y ahi es donde me marca error.
El error dice:

```html
DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid
```

Este es mi codigo para pasar pasarlo de excel a la grilla:

```html
// CREATE A STRING ARRAY USING THE VALUES IN EACH ROW OF THE SHEET.
                        string[] row = new string[] { xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 1].value.ToString(),  
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 2].value, 
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 3].value.ToString(),
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 4].value.ToString(),
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 5].value,
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 6].value,
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 7].value.ToString()};

                        // ADD A NEW ROW TO THE GRID USING THE ARRAY DATA.
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Esta es mi estructura del excel y los datos en el:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo recibir la columas 4 de excel en mi columna ComboBoxColumn?

Comment: Creo que sería volver a vincular el Datasource del excel y mostrarlo, es lo que se me ocurre, Y puede que haya algo mas elegante.

Comment: algo asi como en lugar de agregarlos directamente al datagrid, pasarlos a un datatable o dataset y pasarlo al datagrid por el datasource?

Comment: si en un datatable y luego al datagrid por datasource exacto!